# database entry exist but search_result return false

Tags: php

```
<?php
require 'database.php';

//if (!empty($_POST['search'])):

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM cookies2 WHERE  cookie LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";

$request1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
$request1->bindparam(':search', $_POST['search']);

$request1->execute();
$result1 = $request1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($request1);
$ff = $result1['cookie'];
//endif;
?>
<html>


<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
<body>


<form action="comments.php" method="post"/>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search for user comments"/>
<input type="submit"/>

    <?php
    if(!empty($request1)):
    while($search_result = $request1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    var_dump($search_result);?>

    <h1>baaaaaa</h1>
    <p><?= $search_result['cookie']?></p>
    <h3><?= $search_result['comment']?></h3><?php }


 endif;
?>



</body>
</html>
```

So I am writing script for my cookie app.
And This script works just fine in another page.php
to search for cookies 
but I been stuck 2 days and loop wont start and 
search_result return false most of the times.
Is my bindparam wrong or have I missed some basic indenting?
I want to have this table for user comments on specific cookies.
to search for.
I am writing this in danger get banned my last question probably.
I like stack overflow but its not for beginners I guess.
All feedback is welcome I don't know what is wrong
when almost identic script worked before this.
regards. don

ps baaaa is showing sometimes and the loop don't show and even though I have 
ie bak in table nothing shows,
and I have been looking for similar posts but nothing is as my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query statements like this:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM cookies2 WHERE  cookie LIKE :search"; // Changed line no.1

$request1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
$request1->bindparam(':search', "%".$_POST['search']."%", PDO::PARAM_STR); // Changed line no.2

$request1->execute();
$result1 = $request1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($request1);
```

For more details: [See](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: thanks both solutions worked but i dont know how to add in PDO::PARAM_STR

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind to placeholders in prepared statements; you have no placeholder

So create the placeholder without quotes, because binding handles that for you cleanly.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM cookies2 WHERE  cookie LIKE :search";
```

and then wrap the search argument in the wildcards before binding

```
$request1->bindparam(':search', '%' . $_POST['search'] . '%');
```